# My phone is not transmitting

Tags: htc-desire, headphones

I have an Htc Desire and I'm using the headset that came with it. During a call yesterday the other party stopped hearing me.  I unplugged the headset and continued with the conversation normally. Today I checked the headphones again before buying a new pair and indeed the other person couldn't hear me. What was really surprising is that I could hear myself,  echo with about a second of delay. So, electronically my headphones work. Is there something broken in my phone?

Update: I just tried the Skype test call and it worked just fine, so it seems to be my headset when making phone calls, which is really weird.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's hard to say. Its either your phone, your headset or both of them. I'd say: go to a shop, ask to test a new one. If they work: buy them, its just your headset.

If they don't work: Test your headset in another phone. If they work: it's your phone. If they don't: its your phone AND you headset.